# Solutions to $\lfloor 2x\rfloor-\lfloor x+1\rfloor=2x$

Tags: calculus, number-theory, functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Find all solutions to $$[2x]-[x+1]=2x$$
>   where $[x]=\lfloor x\rfloor$

$$$$
I divided this into 2 cases:

$$Case 1:x=[x]+\{x\}\text{ where } 0\le\{x\}<0.5$$
$$Case 1:x=[x]+\{x\}\text{ where } 0.5\le\{x\}<1$$
$$$$
$$Case1$$$$$$
$[2x]=2[x], [x+1]=[x]+1. 2x=2[x]+2\{x\}$
$$\Rightarrow [2x]-[x+1]=2[x]-[x]-1=2[x]+2\{x\}$$
$$-[x]-1=2\{x\}$$
Now $0\le\{x\}<1,$ thus $0\le 2\{x\}=-[x]-1<2$
$$\Rightarrow -1\ge[x]>-3$$

Thus either $[x]=-1$ or $[x]=-2$.
$$$$If $[x]=-1\Rightarrow 2\{x\}=-(-1)-1=0\Rightarrow\{x\}=0$. 
Thus $x=[x]+\{x\}=-1$$$$$
If $[x]=-2\Rightarrow 2\{x\}=-(-2)-1=1\Rightarrow\{x\}=0.5$. 
Thus $x=[x]+\{x\}=-1.5$$$$$
However, it is clear that $x=-1.5$ does not satisfy the original equation. Similarly in case 2, I am getting one of the 2 possible values of $x$ as $0$, which also does not satisfy the original equation.$$$$
Could somebody please explain $where$ I've gone wrong? Many thanks in anticipation!

Comment: You got that x = -1 and x = -1.5 were the only two possible values for case 1 that *can* satisfy the original equation.  That doesn't mean the both *have* to satisfy the original equation.  It doesn't even mean *either* have to.  You've done nothing wrong.  x = -1 and x = -1.5 are the only possible case 1 solutions.  x = -1 is one and x = -1.5 is not one.   That's not a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only did Case 1 - it is clear that you needed $\{x\} <0.5$ and thus $=0.5$ will not satisfy Case 1. Thus, this is not a solution.

Similarly, in case 2 - "I am getting one of the 2 possible values of $x$ as 0" - you need $\{x\}\ge 0.5$, and thus $=0$ does not satisfy the case.

So, the solution should be intersected with the case.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had quite forgotten about the conditions in Case 1!

Answer (score 1):

$$\lfloor\mathrm{2}{x}\rfloor−\lfloor{x}+\mathrm{1}\rfloor=\mathrm{2}{x} \\ $$
$$\lfloor\mathrm{2}{x}\rfloor−\lfloor{x}+\mathrm{1}\rfloor=\lfloor\mathrm{2}{x}\rfloor \\ $$
$$\lfloor{x}+\mathrm{1}\rfloor=\mathrm{0}\Rightarrow{x}=\left[-\mathrm{1};\mathrm{0}\right) \\ $$
$$\mathrm{2}{x}=\lfloor\mathrm{2}{x}\rfloor=\left\{-\mathrm{2},-\mathrm{1}\right\} \\ $$
$${x}=\left\{-\mathrm{1},-\frac{\mathrm{1}}{\mathrm{2}}\right\} \\ $$

Answer (score 0):

The left hand side of your equation is an integer, so the right hand side must be an integer as well. Therefore {x} is either $1/2$ or $0$. If it is zero, you have the following equation:

$2x-(x+1)=2x$ which means $x=-1$.

{x}$=1/2$ then again $[2x]=2x$ and you will get $[x+1]=0$, which means $x=-1/2$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that neither value works. But I'm interested in knowing $why$ my method is giving an incorrect answer, or where I've gone wrong in my working.